# ImageMagick not resizing text

Tags: bash, imagemagick

I'm writing a script that will generate card images, in bash. The cards contain a description of the spell that fills the majority of the page. To add this description to the card I use this:

```
convert -transparent white -fill black -size 161x170 \
        caption:"${newfinisheddescription}" \
        ${tempdir}${newspellfilename}.png \
        +swap -gravity north -geometry +0+77 -composite \
        ${tempdir}${newspellfilename}.png
```

where the variables are simply directories and filenames, and `newfinisheddescription` is the text starting with "casting Time...". Starting from a blank card (dots not important):

[image][image]

the above call is suppose to change the point size of the text so that it fits description box. The first card made seems ok but it cuts a bit of the text off:

[image: first card]

Later another card is generated where there is less text but its point size is smaller:

[image: Armor of Agathya]

Is there something I'm doning wrong in my image magick call?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are doing without seeing your starting image! Also what is in your text string? Is it `1st level Conjuration` or `Armor of Agathya` or both? And the sizes of your cards are 187x262, which doesn't make sense, to me at least! If your text is 170px tall and your card is 262px tall, surely your text should more than half fill the card? But it doesn't.

Comment: The text string is the body of text that should fill more than half the card and thats the issue, it is not filling the entire space

Comment: Please post a full-size card before you have modified it... and answer my question about what your text is.